# How to give effects to image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, filter, uiimage

I want user to pick an image from gallery then user cab give multiple effects to the image like grey color,vintage,sepia,retro etc.I have searched a lot for the solution.Please guide how can i achieve this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Download the Apple UIImage+effects category on UIImage and tweak it for your use.

Answer (score 1):

Use Core Image Framework by Apple. Cheers! [This will help you](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGammaAdjust)

Answer (score 1):

if you just simply wants apply the effects which you described you can use [these](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIGammaAdjust)

or you want to apply many different filters and also make new filters to apply on that images use [GPUImage Framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)
its very fast and easy..

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this demo.

https://github.com/yackle/CLImageEditor

This is the better then anything.

Thanks